# React 16. Updating npm modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Whether there is an opportunity to update all the packages in the node_modules for using with React 16 (propTypes and createClass)
Is there way to update all packages to prop-types instead React.propTypes (or createClass)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way: **coding!** Remove your node_modules and your lock file (package-lock.json if you are using `npm` or yarn.lock if you are using `yarn`); update your package.json to use React 16; .then change your code accordingly and run your `npm | yarn install`.